# Configuring Ruby On Rails Application With Iex-Ruby-Client Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner programmer.  I recently built an application that uses the iex-ruby-client gem to pull stock quotes for me that I enter into a webpage form. It worked perfectly.

However, in early June, IEX changed their API so that you have to have a publishable token from the IEX cloud console.  I got my publishable token from IEX cloud console.

The updated gem docs (https://github.com/dblock/iex-ruby-client) say that I have to "Configure" the application now.  I simply don't know how or where I would implement the configuration code.  Here is the suggested code from the gem documentation.  I just don't know where to put it.

```
Configure IEX::Api.configure do |config|
  config.publishable_token = 'token' # defaults to 
  ENV['IEX_API_PUBLISHABLE_TOKEN']
  config.endpoint = 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/v1' # defaults to 
  'https://cloud.iexapis.com/v1'
end
```

The documents also state, "You can also configure an instance of a client directly."

```
client = IEX::Api::Client.new(
  publishable_token: 'token',
  endpoint: 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/v1'
)
```

I am adding extra code to clarify what I have done based on the response here.  Here is my new config/initializers/iex-ruby-client.rb file (token info isn't the real one).

```
IEX::Api.configure do |config|
  config.publishable_token = 'pk_3b38fsdadfsafjsdalfjdsakfjlda12f519'
  config.endpoint = 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/v1' 
end
```

Here is the relevant method in the controller where I require the library:

```
def index
  require 'iex-ruby-client'
  if params[:id] == ""
    @nothing = "You forgot to enter a symbol ;)."
  elsif

  if params[:id]
    begin
    @stock = IEX::Resources::Quote.get(params[:id])
    @company = IEX::Resources::Company.get(params[:id])
    rescue StandardError
    @error = "That stock symbol doesn't seem to exist. Please enter 
      another symbol."
    end
  end
end
end
```

So I have created the config file and required the gem at the top of the method, but I am still getting an error.  I'm sure there is some flaw in my implementation of this token requirement.  If you have any additional suggestions, I welcome them.  But if this is too much to ask on Stack Overflow, I understand.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you clearly have two choices:

1. use [initializer](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/configuring.html#using-initializers) by creating a config file(i.e: `iex_client.rb`) under the directory `/config/initializers` and add:

```
Configure IEX::Api.configure do |config|
  config.publishable_token = 'token' # defaults to 
  ENV['IEX_API_PUBLISHABLE_TOKEN']
  config.endpoint = 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/v1' # defaults to 
  'https://cloud.iexapis.com/v1'
end
```

2. just use the client object wherever you want like this:

```
client = IEX::Api::Client.new(
  publishable_token: 'token',
  endpoint: 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/v1'
)
```

You probably need to replace `token` with a correct one. You also need to make sure to `require` the library wherever you wanna use it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try to implement both your suggestions. To clarify your final point, I don't know how to require a library. Is this something I do in the controller or elsewhere as well? Is the name of the library just the name of the gem itself?

Comment: yes. you could include your library using `require 'iex-ruby-client'`

Comment: I tried to implement Gilg Him's suggestion to create a config file and to require the library in the controller.  I have added the code above.  Still pulling an error.  I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: "That stock symbol doesn't seem to exist. Please enter another symbol." This is coming from the "@error" in the final block of code I pasted above.

Comment: I can add a link to the entire repo if you want.  But I understand if you don't have time or this is too deep in the weeds.

Answer (score 0):

After unsuccessfully attempting to configure the IEX-ruby-client gem (as described in my question here on stack overflow), I switched over to the stock_quote gem.  That gem is built off of the same IEX API, and I had no problems configuring the app with a stock_quote.rb file saved inside config/initializers.